# How to resize element's width to the actual content within it on 1 line?

Tags: html, css, wrapper

Ok, so jsFiddle of my problem here:  http://jsfiddle.net/Cn8ek/ and here:  http://jsfiddle.net/Cn8ek/1/  Fullscreen result of the first jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Cn8ek/embedded/result/

I have been trying to have the width of the blue background in the fiddles, set to `auto` so that it resizes in the same way that the Red Ribbon CSS does (to the content inside of it), however, no matter what I do it is always the same size: 100% of the available width, minus the padding-left and padding-right of the 3rd parent above that element with a class of `content_slider_text_block_wrap`

The CSS I'm using for the element with the class of `sub_head_text`, which is the element that I need to resize in width according to the text that is within the element is as follows:

```
.content_slider_text_block_wrap .sub_head_text {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: .8em;
    margin: -0.5em;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
    position: relative;
}

.content_slider_text_block_wrap .sub_head {
    padding: 0 .3em;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: -40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #212D3B;
    font-family: "MissionGothic-Regular", "Mission Gothic Regular Regular", "mission_gothicregular";
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: #f2efe9;
    -moz-border-radius: .5em;
    -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
    -khtml-border-radius: .5em;
    border-radius: .5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

All of the elements within the HTML DOM are structured like so:

```
<div class="content_slider_text_block_wrap">
    <div class="name_container">
        <div class="sub_head">
            <h1 class="h1_candidates"><span class="sidestar-left">&#9733;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Dan&nbsp;Lawless&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="sidestar-right">&#9733;</span></h1>
            <div class="sub_head_text">Chief Lending Officer&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;Accion Texas, Inc.&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;CITY, STATE</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="centertext">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <a href="#" class="button_regular">More Info</a><!-- button_regular -->
</div>
```

The main issue I am having is how to get the blue background area's width to change according to the content (text) within it.  But needs to be on only 1 line and ofcourse, centered as it is now.  I am using `ems` for the font-size, but that doesn't seem to make any difference when resizing the browser window down either.  How??

The thing that puzzles me the most is How come the Red Ribbon's `h1` element width changes according to the content (text) within it, but the blue background `div` element,  contained within the same parent (as the `h1` element), will not?

Finally, my questions is this:  "How do I resize the blue background, that is in the same parent as the Red Ribbon background according to the text within it, and keep both the blue and Red Ribbon centered within the page?"

Comment: And when I add `non-breaking white spaces - &nbsp;` to the entire line to force it on 1 line within the blue background element, it looks like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/Cn8ek/1/

Comment: Maybe I need to use jQuery?  To calculate the width of the element somehow and apply it?  Or use jQuery to set a left and right percentage or pixel value according to the content within it?  If so, how can this be done?

Comment: This seems to be a couple of questions in one, but it's not very clear which questions. After re-reading your question a couple of times, it seems you ask how to resize the font in the blue sub-head the same way as the font in the red header, it that right? But none of the font sizes change with a resize of the window.

Comment: Anyway, if you use the style `white-space:nowrap` on the appropriate elements, that removes the need for all the `&nbsp;`s, making the source a lot more readable.

Comment: @MrLister - My questions is "How do I resize the blue background's width, that is in the same parent as the Red Ribbon background according to the text within it, and keep both the blue and Red Ribbon centered within the page?"  Maybe this involves taking it out of the same parent as the Red Ribbon?

Comment: So the whole question has nothing to do with keeping the text on one line? OK then. The red header has `display: inline-block`, which is what you are after. So if you give the `.sub-head` that style too, it will be as wide as the text within. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cn8ek/5/) or the [full screen result](http://jsfiddle.net/Cn8ek/5/show).

Comment: OMG, that did it,  AWESOME!  I feel so stupid now!  I tried `display-block` but was applying it to the `sub_head_text` element not the `sub_head` element.